# Toggling leaflet controls ON and OFF?

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I want to toggle the Leaflet layer control when the user clicks in a button.

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(
  {
    '<i class="fas fa-map-marked"></i>': OSM,
    '<i class="fas fa-image"></i>': Esri_WorldImagery
  }, null, {collapsed: false}
).addTo(map);

<button onclick="toggleLayerControl()">toggle control</button>

function toggleLayerControl(){
   if(layerControl.display=="block"){
      layerControl.display = "none";
   }else{
      layerControl.display = "block";
   }
}
```

What's the simplest way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is built in into Leaflet. E.g.:

```
if(layerControls.collapsed) {
  layerControls.expand();
} else {
  layerControls.collapse();
}
```

To toggle visibility of the layer control in the map use:

```
layerControls.addTo(map)    
layerControls.remove()
```

Check out [the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#control-layers) for more info and details.